# css sprite active state still showing on browser Back button

Tags: css, css-sprites

I am trying to use CSS sprites for a Navigation bar. After a lot of Internet research, I think I have determined the 'simplest' way.  All appears to work fine EXCEPT when I click the browser's Back button.  In IE (8.0.6001.18701), the Active state is 'stuck' (looks like button is pushed down).  In Firefox (14.0.1) the Hover state is 'stuck'.  I can live with the Firefox issue as it goes away as soon as the mouse is moved off the Back button, but not the IE issue.  I currently have the navbar in a header file that I use with Includes to keep things simple and consistant.
Here is the Template html.  I use this for all my pages. (when I get past this problem, I will actuall enter in the rest of the bodies)

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DS.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="centerpage">
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="table1">
<tr>
<td>
<!--webbot bot="Include" U-Include="Nav_Includes/Header.htm" TAG="BODY" --></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Enter page data here.<br>
<hr width="770" size="1">
<span id="timestamp">Page last updated: 
<!--webbot bot="Timestamp" S-Type="EDITED" S-Format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p" --></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<!--webbot bot="Include" U-Include="Nav_Includes/Footer.htm" TAG="BODY" --></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the header.htm:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>Dolphin Storage Header</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../DS.css">
</head>
<body>
<img border="0" src="../images/header.jpg" width="760" height="101" align="center">
<p><a class="navHome" href="../index.htm"></a>
<a class="navUnits" href="../units.htm"></a>
<a class="navSpecials" href="../specials.htm"></a>
<a class="navAbout" href="../about.htm"></a>
<a class="navContact" href="../contact.htm"></a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

The css file:

```
body {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
color: #000000;
text-align:center; /* Fix for IE not centering webpage */
background-color: #ffe670;
}
#centerpage {
width: 770px; 
margin: 0 auto;   /* Top & Bottom = 0, Right & Left = auto to center the page horizontally */
text-align:left;  /* 2nd part of IE fix for centering webpage */
}
/* Navagation bar, using 'sprite' images */ 
a.navHome {
display: block;
float: left;
width: 160px;
height: 30px;
background-image: url('Nav_Buttons/Home.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position; 0 0;
}
a.navHome:hover {
background-position: 0 -30px;
}
a.navHome:active {
background-position: 0 -60px;
}

a.navUnits {
display: block;
float: left;
width: 150px;
height: 30px;
background-image: url('Nav_Buttons/Units.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position; 0 0;
}
a.navUnits:hover {
background-position: 0 -30px;
}
a.navUnits:active {
background-position: 0 -60px;
}

a.navSpecials {
display: block;
float: left;
width: 150px;
height: 30px;
background-image: url('Nav_Buttons/Specials.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position; 0 0;
}
a.navSpecials:hover {
background-position: 0 -30px;
}
a.navSpecials:active {
background-position: 0 -60px;
}

a.navAbout {
display: block;
float: left;
width: 150px;
height: 30px;
background-image: url('Nav_Buttons/About.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position; 0 0;
}
a.navAbout:hover {
background-position: 0 -30px;
}
a.navAbout:active {
background-position: 0 -60px;
}

a.navContact {
display: block;
float: left;
width: 160px;
height: 30px;
background-image: url('Nav_Buttons/Contact.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position; 0 0;
}
a.navContact:hover {
background-position: 0 -30px;
}
a.navContact:active {
background-position: 0 -60px;
}

#timestamp {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
color: #000000;
font-size: xx-small;
}

H5 {
font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
color: #035f8e;
}
```

Sprites: (won't let a new user post images, sorry)

Comment: Please note, the incorrect semi-colon ";" after some of the background-positions has been corrected to a colon ":", but did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `:link` and `:visited` pseudo classes to set all the common default states prior to defining the individual `:hover` and `:active` states using the [lvha principle](http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/link-specificity.html):

```
a.navUnits:link, a.navUnits:visited, a.navSpecials:link, a.navSpecials:visited, a.navAbout:link, a.navAbout:active, a.navContact:link, a.navContact:visited, a.navHome:link, a.navHome:visited { background-position: 0 0; }
```